# What is the difference between malware signatures and malware artifacts?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware, malware-analysis

I am trying to analyse some malware samples but I am trying to understand the differen between malware signatures and malware artifacts. As far as I understand (and from what I've understood from this other post: [What is the difference between artifact and evidence](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138118/what-is-the-difference-between-artifact-and-evidence)) both terms can be defined as follows:

Signatures: Specific actions/changes/files which are specific to particular malware and, thus, are known to be malicious.

Artifacts: Actions/changes/files which have created by a program and which must be analysed to know if they are malicious or not.

Could you please tell me if it's correct or not and elaborate on my definitions? I would really appreciate it.